# How to generate the following XML File with the XML Framework Simple

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

How can I generate a XML request file with the structure below using Simple?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ft>
    <request clientId="123" apiName="api_search_location_stops_nearby" apiVersion="2.0">
        <client clientId="123"/>
        <requestType>api_search_location_stops_nearby</requestType>
        <outputCoords>WGS84</outputCoords>
        <fromCoordName>WGS84</fromCoordName>
        <fromType>coords</fromType>
        <fromWgs84Lat>48.22</fromWgs84Lat>
        <fromWgs84Lon>16.39</fromWgs84Lon>
    </request>
</ft>
```

To generate the part `<request> ... </request>` is easy, but how can I add the XML open tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and the `<ft>` and the end tag `</ft>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are already able to generate the `<request>...</request>` tag, I assume that you already have a `Request` object with the correct fields and so on, so in fact it is really simple..

```
@Root
public class Ft {
    @Element
    private Request request;

    // constructor, getter, setter if needed
}
```

In order to generate the XML prolog you need to create your own `Formatter/Serializer` with the [`Format(String)` constructor](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/stream/Format.html#Format%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister(//
    new Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>"));
Ft ft = new Ft(); 
ft.setRequest(myRequest);
serializer.write(ft, new File("ft.xml"));
```